Trigger event if both conditions are met
I would like to change the colour of different regions if both are clicked. I can work around this with
j = 1; DynamicModule[{col = Green}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 3}], 
    EdgeForm[None], Dynamic@col, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
    Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300], {"MouseDown" :> 
    If[Or[MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]] > 0 && 
        MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]] < 1 && 
        MousePosition["Graphics"][[2]] > 0 && 
        MousePosition["Graphics"][[2]] < 1, 
       MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]] > 2 && 
        MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]] < 3 && 
        MousePosition["Graphics"][[2]] > 2 && 
        MousePosition["Graphics"][[2]] < 3] && 
      j == 2, (col = 
       col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red}), ++j]}]]

but it isn't stable. I would like to only change the colour if both regions are clicked.
Ideally, I would also like j to reset to 0 if the white area is clicked.

DynamicModule[{colors = {Green, Green, Red}, i = 1, j = 0, r1 = False, r2 = False}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 3}], 
    EdgeForm[None], Dynamic@colors[[i]], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
    Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}]}, ImageSize -> 300],
  {"MouseDown" :>
    Which[
     RegionMember[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
       MousePosition["Graphics"]] && ! r1 && ! r2, {i++, r1 = True},
     RegionMember[Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}], 
       MousePosition["Graphics"]] && r1 && ! r2, {i++, r2 = True},
     RegionMember[Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}], 
       MousePosition["Graphics"]] && ! r1 && ! r2, {i++, r2 = True},
     RegionMember[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
       MousePosition["Graphics"]] && r2 && ! r1, {i++, r1 = True},
     !RegionMember[
        RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
         Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}]], MousePosition["Graphics"]] && i == 3,
     {i = 1; r1 = False; r2 = False}
     ]}]]



Thak you - this is great
